# How to install Docker Engine on Debian without adding sources to apt or third party keys?

Tags: linux, docker

The Docker Engine containerd runtime is open source and should be available through the main Debian repo, but all the guides I have found ask you to install a third party software sources and gpg keys, mainly Docker Inc's.

What's the process of natively installing Docker Engine on Debian?

To clarify, I do not want to add a third-party licensing and security liabilities to my apt sources.

Comment: Adding another source to your debian repositories doesn't change the licensing, it's Apache 2.0 no matter how you install it. Security updates to the debian repos will almost always lag the updates to the docker repos.

Comment: @BMitch You're right that Docker engine is **currently** Apache 2, but they can at their discretion change that... the Debian main repository tries to guarantee unrestricted licenses... other repositories don't typically make that guarantee. Docker Inc has been changing licenses around it's products very recently... currently the changes don't affect Docker engine... **currently**. https://www.docker.com/blog/updating-product-subscriptions/ lol at the kb's vote ratio feature at the bottom of that page

Comment: Docker hasn't changed any licenses, what was OSS before is still OSS today. What they changed was the terms on the closed source Desktop product. I'm not even sure they can change the license on an Apache 2 project once they accepted public contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker.io` is the open source version of docker/containerd in the Debian sid repository.

For just docker:
`sudo apt-get install docker.io`

If you need docker-compose, you can get it from the unstable repository or install it from git, it's just a few python scripts so it's easy to install from source.

docker-compose https://docs.linuxserver.io/general/docker-compose

Source: https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/docker.io
Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 amd64 and Ubuntu 21.10 arm64